# AWS Data pipeline postStepCommand unable to access INPUT1_STAGING_DIR

Tags: amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

In EMR Activity of a Data pipline, I am trying to use postStepCommand (as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emractivity.html) ) to invoke a shell script. As part of it I am trying to access the standard directory paths **${INPUT1_STAGING_DIR} and ${OUTPUT1_STAGING_DIR}**

But seems like it's not able to access it's value. Is it by design ?